# Study $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-1+\log{n}-\log{(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**Problem:** I have to study $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-1+\log{n}-\log{(n+1)}$$ with respect to $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

**My work:**

$$e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-1+\log{n}-\log(n+1)=e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}+\log{(\frac{n}{n+1})}-1=e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}+\log{(1-\frac{1}{n+1})}-1$$ Now:
$$e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-1+\log{(1-\frac{1}{n+1})}=  \frac{1}{n^a}+o(\frac{1}{n^a})+\frac{-1}{n+1}+o(\frac{-1}{n+1})$$
Since if $a<1$ then $\frac{1}{n^a}+o(\frac{1}{n^a})+\frac{-1}{n+1}+o(\frac{-1}{n+1})= \frac{1}{n^a}+o(\frac{1}{n^a})\sim \frac{1}{n^a}$, then if I consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^a}$ is convergent only for $a>1$, and this is not the case. So for $a<1$ the series is divergent.

If $a>1$ I have $\frac{1}{n^a}+o(\frac{1}{n^a})+\frac{-1}{n+1}+o(\frac{-1}{n+1})=\frac{-1}{n+1}+o(\frac{-1}{n+1})\sim \frac{-1}{n}$ and again $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{n}$ is divergent.

If $a=1$ then $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}+o(\frac{1}{n^{2}})+\frac{-1}{n+1}+\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}+o(\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2})= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{2n^2(n+1)^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})\sim \frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^2}+o(1/n^2)\sim \frac{1}{n^2}+o(1/n^2)$

So then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent. So the series is convergent only for $a=1$.

$\textbf{Questions:}$

1. My attempt is correct?
2. I have applied the asymptote criterion but first of all I have to verify that I am in case of positive series terms. But I am in trouble to prove $e^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-1+\log{n}-\log{n+1}>0$, how can I do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123772/discussion-on-question-by-cely-study-sum-n1-inftye-frac1na-1-lo).

Answer (score 1):

For (2), note that
$$e^{1/n}-1 \ge 1/n \qquad\text{and}\qquad \log(n+1)-\log n = \int_n^{n+1}\frac 1x \,dx$$ where the integrand is $\le 1/n$ everywhere in the interval.

However, this will not complete your task because (as noted in the comment thread) your estimations to order $o(1/n)$ are too crude to be sure everything cancels out correctly. One way to repair this is to work to order $O(1/n^2)$ instead of $o(1/n)$, as Bernard suggested -- but I think it's more instructive to view the entire exercise from a different angle:

**The log terms telescope.** If you write out the partial sums you get
$$ s_k = \sum_{n=1}^k e^{1/n^a} - 1 + \log n - \log(n+1)
= \Bigl( \sum_{n=1}^k e^{1/n^a} - 1\Bigr) - \log(k+1) $$
So one way to think of what's going on here is that we're summing $e^{1/n^a}-1$, but we expect that to diverge to $+\infty$ so we subtract $\log(k+1)$ from the partial sums in the hope that the *difference* will at least converge to something interesting.

It's fairly easy to see that this can only work if $a=1$. if $a$ is too large, the sum of $\sum e^{1/n^a}$ alone *converges*, and then our original sum diverges to $-\infty$ due to ever larger logarithms being subtracted from it. But if $a$ is too *small*, then $\sum(e^{1/n^a} - 1)$ diverges too fast to be saved by the logarithm -- an integral comparison will show that the partial sums grow at least as fast as $k^{1-a}$, which eventually outpaces the logarithm.

So there's only the $a=1$ case to handle. In that case, the most informative way to get through is to split the summed part into two:

$$ s_k = \Bigl( \sum_{n=1}^k e^{1/n} - \frac1n \Bigr) + \Bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac1n \Bigr) - \log(k+1) $$

The *first* of these sums *converges* -- we can show that the term is asymptotic to $1/n^2$ by expanding the exponential to the second power. Ho hum.

The *second* sum is the definition of the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_k$. And if you already know that $H_k - \log(k+1)$ tends to a finite limit (the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*), then you're done here.

Otherwise, here's a proof of that standard fact:
$$
\begin{align} H_k - \log(k+1) ={}& \Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^k \frac1n\Bigr) - \log(k+1)
\\ ={}& \sum_{n=1}^k \Bigl(\frac1n - \bigl(\log(k+1) - \log k\bigr) \Bigr)
\\ ={}& \sum_{n=1}^k \Bigl(\frac1n - \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac1x\,dx \Bigr)
\\ ={}& \sum_{n=1}^k \int_n^{n+1} \Big( \frac1n - \frac1x \Bigr)\,dx
\\ <{}& \sum_{n=1}^k \int_n^{n+1} \Big( \frac1n - \frac1{n+1} \Bigr)\,dx
\\ ={}& \sum_{n=1}^k \Big( \frac1n - \frac1{n+1} \Bigr)
\\ ={}& \frac11 - \frac1{n+1} < 1
\end{align}
$$
We also see (clearest just before the first $<$) that $H_k-\log(k+1)$ is *increasing*. And an increasing bounded sequence converges.